# sed '/^$/d' in perl

Tags: perl, sed

How to do this sed empty line delete with perl: `sed '/^$/d'`

there is `print unless` method but I mean something more 'just like in sed' as you make substitude by `perl -ne 's/<pattern//g'`

Comment: `print if (!/^$/)`

Comment: Can you afford to have a copy of this file while the script is running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print lines that contain at least one non-whitespace character:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\S/;'
```

To skip empty lines:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^$/;'
```